Sol adress stuck in my phantom app
How can I recover my Sol adress?
I have bought a miner and activated it by getting my sol adress of phantom and not of the miner. Now the miner is showing me in phantom but I cannot send the adress anywhere. How do I do it. Please help me!!!
